# Silverlight and ASP.Net - Service Reference not working

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-services

So I have a Silverlight project with WCF/RIA services enabled (as per requested when starting a new project) on my ASP.Net stuff, I have some services on that end that I would like the Silverlight client to be hooked up to... Problem - for some reason I keep on getting the same error when I attempt to make a service reference:

- I have multiple services (in a folder: [SERVER_PROJECT] \Services\ [SERVICE_FILE])
- The services are of different types
- The services are being discovered BUT will not be downloaded, below is the error message I keep on getting.

*"There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address."*

Any advice would be appreciated and please feel free to ask for any information I've not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing the WCF service outside Silverlight?  Open the service endpoint with a browser to make sure the service is working correctly.

Comment: Okay, some progress - I got more detailed error:

The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.

Do you know where I should add this in the Web.config file?

[EDIT:] Sorry, I'm newbie! This goes in the service file!?